# Best practice for (BPM) process control url structure (like REST)?

Tags: url, standards, business-process-management

Currently I am looking for a "best practice url structure" for (BPM) process control. IMHO a process should not be controlled via a RESTful API.

Are there any standards or best practices for this?

**Further explanations:**

I start a new process instance of type "approval" for workitem "0815":

```
[PUT]http://server/process/approval/0815/start
```

I approve that process (yes, there can only be one such process for a workitem):

```
[PUT]http://server/process/approval/0815/approve
```

One more thing: everything is asynchronous here! So I get a 202 which means that the process handler will try to execute the command on the process.

Comment: Clarify, please, what you imply under "process control"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry if the answer is a bit disappointing but I believe there is no such thing as a best practice or standard for using REST in that context.

Given that BPM is not a standard (it is a methodology), this leaves the door open for an "unlimited" number of technical implementations for BPMS vendors.

The answer on how to use REST APIs to control you processes will most likely depend on vendor-specific APIs.

Modern BPMS such as Bonita BPM expose such APIs out of the box. If you have to implement your own APIs, you might want to consider looking at those.

Cheers,